# Как учесть плотность/разрешение экрана в при drawBitmap в Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Например, на одном устройстве изображение целое, на втором, поновее, фото только половину. Из-за чего это может быть? Из-за плотности или разрешения экрана? Как это можно устранить? [image: фото бага]

Создаю bitmap так

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(picture, 0, 0, 1024,1024, matrix, true) 
matrix.postScale(0.1f)
```

Comment: по классике для каждого вида разрешения делается свой рисунок в ресурсах в специальных модификаторах, например, xhdpi и тп

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте, вместо 1024, воспользоваться методом

```
/**метод преобразования dip в px
 * dip - Density-independent Pixels.
 * Абстрактная ЕИ, позволяющая приложениям выглядеть одинаково
 * на различных экранах и разрешениях*/
public static int dip2px(final Context context, int dip) {
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dip,
            context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```